IronPDF weird behavior in test env when digitally signed, file generated is 0 kb in size
I have a weird issue. Recently I was asked to digitally sign a PDF. So I did a bit of research and used adobe acrobat to generate a .PFX file as well as .CER FILE.
I also licensed the IronPDF library so I have a key for it.
On my desktop, everything is working great. Product is licensed, no watermarks, and file is digitally singed.
HOWEVER, then I have my test rdp..
I applied the code in that rdp, and indeed the IronPDF watermark was removed.
The weird behavior is: as soon as I digitally sign in my test rdp, I do get a log that it is licensed and that it was signed. But, the file created is 0 kb, though, when logging the file pagecount and more, it says it contains 4 pages for example.
Once I remove key, the file created is good in size but file isn't being signed.
At part it seems like there's an issue with both signing and licensing the product.
The code here will show the log of the file right when I save and sign in on my TEST rdp.
Though the log is a mess right now because I was trying many things
2024-04-16 09:21:28.200 +03:00 [INF]The software is licensed.
2024-04-16 09:21:45.730 +03:00 [INF][MaagarTviotController - Post() method] calling SheiltaLebaalRechevPdf.init()
2024-04-16 09:21:48.221 +03:00 [INF]Generated PDF page count: 4
2024-04-16 09:21:48.221 +03:00 [INF]Pages were created successfully.
2024-04-16 09:21:48.228 +03:00 [INF]File was successfully saved at location C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MaagarTviotApi\MaagarLiav\Pdfs\
2024-04-16 09:21:48.229 +03:00 [INF]Looking for the digital signature certificate
2024-04-16 09:21:48.282 +03:00 [INF]File was successfully signed!

For this method:
public string SavePdfFile(string LocalDirectory, string FileName, string FtpPath = null, string footerContent = null, CustomFont font = null)
{
    try
    {
        // Instantiate Renderer
        var renderer = new ChromePdfRenderer
                {
                    RenderingOptions =
                          {
                              MarginTop = 12,
                              MarginLeft = 20,
                              MarginRight = 20,
                              MarginBottom = 12,

                              HtmlFooter = new HtmlHeaderFooter()
                                  {
                                      MaxHeight = 15,
                                      HtmlFragment = $"<div style='text-align: center; {font.BuildFontCss()}'>{footerContent} {{page}}</div>",
                                      DrawDividerLine = false
                                  }
                          }
                };

        var pdfdoc = renderer.RenderHtmlAsPdf(htmlPage.ToString());

        // Log the actual page count for debugging purposes
        Log.Information($"Generated PDF page count: {pdfdoc.PageCount}");

        if (pdfdoc.PageCount == 0)
        {
            Log.Error("No pages were created in the PDF document.");
        }
        else
        {
            Log.Information("Pages were created successfully.");
        }

        pdfdoc.SaveAs(LocalDirectory + FileName); // Saves our PdfDocument object as a PDF

        Log.Information($"File was successfully saved at location {LocalDirectory}");
        Log.Information("Looking for the digital signature certificate");

        var signature = new IronPdf.Signing.PdfSignature(@"C:\PdfSignatureCertificate\TestCertification.pfx", password)
                            {
                                SignatureDate = DateTime.Now
                            };
        signature.SignPdfFile(LocalDirectory + FileName);

        Log.Information("File was successfully signed!");

        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(FtpPath))
        {
            new SFtpUtilCore().saveFileToFtp(LocalDirectory, FileName, FtpPath);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Error($"Error with certificate: {ex.Message}");
    }

    Log.Information(htmlPage.ToString());

    return htmlPage.ToString();
}

To be honest, it drives me nuts. What am I doing wrong? What is it that I'm missing?
It all began since the file that is signed didn't show any sign of being signed.
So I thought maybe it's because I had trial version of IronPDF in my test env, but, personally I don't think that is the issue.
Thanks for any help!
